# fixed width record of actual data stream but with following awk field splitting ( FS, FIELDWIDTHS, FPAT)

Tags: awk

i changed my question - very simple
**how can you read out this data with awk?**
knowing -
one record has size 29 characters
3 fields per record - sizes: 15, 10, 4

Can it be done with using field splitting (FIELDWIDTHS) of awk?
data is about 2MB long:

```
4harddisk-------412999238---13cdrom-------------488388---22floppy-----------4994942---31mouse-----------20303202---4
```

**first record:** "4harddisk-------412999238---1"
**first field:**  "4harddisk-" -> "4harddisk"
**second field:** can contain letters and numbers "------412999238" -> output "412999238"
**third field:** can be a number from 0-9999 "---1" -> output "1"

my tries:
very slow - first getline with RS=".{29}" to get the data into RT - second getline two way pipe to cat with RS="^$" to force awk to split into fields

```
awk '
function load_fixedWidth_record (width, setFields,     command)
   {
   if (width==0) { $0=""; RT=""; return 1; }
   
   RS=".{" width "}"; command="cat";
   if (getline)
      {
      if (length(RT)>0)                      #-- RT contains the record, $0 is empty
         {
         if (setFields)
            {
            printf "%s",RT |& command; close (command, "to");
            RS="^$"; command |& getline;     #-- Sets $0, NF, and RT

            close(command, "from");
            }
         else { $0=RT; RT=""; }
         return 1;
         }
      else return 0;                         #-- record is last one and record length was smaller than width, $0 contains the record, RT=""
      }
   else return -1;
   }
   
BEGIN {
FIELDWIDTHS="15 10 4";
load_fixedWidth_record(29, 1);
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i;
} ' <<< "4harddisk-------412999238---13cdrom-------------488388---22floppy-----------4994942---31mouse-----------20303202---4"
```

my second try - own function does the split according to FIELDSWIDTH
but isnt there an easier way, that awk does the job automatic?

```
awk '
#-- loads a fixed width record of the actual datastream into $0, returns the load success
#--   if setFields is true, set fields according to PROCINFO["FS"]
#--   success: -1 ... already on end of datastream, 0 ... record smaller than width, end of datastream reached, 1 ... success
function load_fixedWidth_record (width, setFields,    new_RS, fields, i, j, l, str_pos, skip, take, dp, star_found, star_i, star_strPos, star_skip, star_take, substring_ARR)
   {
   if (width==0) { $0=""; RT=""; return 1; }
   
   new_RS=".{" width "}";             #-- setting RS to often can immensly slow down the execution, i saved the old RS and restored it back
   if (RS!=new_RS) RS=new_RS;         #-- every time after function execution, this slowed down the function by 100times, i removed it
   
   if (getline)
      {
      if (length(RT)>0)               #-- RT contains the record, $0 is empty
         {
         if (setFields)
            {
            switch (PROCINFO["FS"])
               {
               case "FS": split(RT, fields); for (i in fields) $i=fields[i]; NF=length(fields); break;
               
               case "FIELDWIDTHS":
                  split(FIELDWIDTHS,fields," "); str_pos=1; star_i=0; j=1;
                  for (i in fields)
                     {
                     star_found=0; skip=0; dp=index(fields[i],":");                                               #-- search for doublepoint dp
                     if (dp) 
                        {
                        skip=substr(fields[i],1,dp-1); take=substr(fields[i],dp+1);                               #-- field descriptor ... skip:take ... supports also - *:3 or 5:* and any * in the middle of fields, but awk supports only * at last field
                        if (take=="*") star_found=1; else take=strtonum(take);                                    #-- search for take *, else str to number
                        if (skip=="*") { if (take=="*") skip=0; else star_found=1; } else skip=strtonum(skip);    #-- search for skip *, else str to number, "*:*" becomes "0:*"
                        }
                     else if (take=="*") star_found=1; else take=strtonum(take);
       
                     if (star_found)
                        {
                        if (star_i==0)                                                                            #-- star found - save star values
                           {                                                                                      #-- and reserve two element places in substring_ARR (j+=2)  
                           star_i=i; star_strPos=str_pos; 
                           star_skip=skip; star_take=take;
                           j+=2; continue;
                           }
                        continue;                                                                                 #-- if more stars are found in other field descriptors, skip the complete field
                        }
                     else
                        {
                        str_pos+=skip; substring_ARR[j++]=str_pos;                                                #-- build substring_ARR  elements 1,3,5, ... save index where to cut
                        substring_ARR[j++]=take; str_pos+=take;                                                   #--                      elements 2,4,6, ... save how many chars to cut
                        }                                                                                         #-- field 1: element 1, element 2; field 2: element 3, element 4; ...                                                                                  
                     }
                     
                  if (star_i>0)                                                                                      #-- star found - fill reserved empty places in substring_ARR for star field
                     {
                     if (star_take=="*") { star_take=length(RT)-star_skip; if (length(star_take<0)) star_take=0; }   #-- calculate star_take; if (<0) star_take=0;
                     else { star_skip=length(RT)-star_take; if (star_skip<0) star_skip=0; }                          #-- calculate star_skip; if (<0) star_skip=0;
                     
                     i=star_skip+star_take;                                                                          #-- save star field length in i
                     if (i>0)                                                                                        #-- if field length >0 fill reserved places
                        {
                        j=star_i*2-1; substring_ARR[j++]=star_strPos+star_skip; substring_ARR[j++]=star_take;        
                        l=length(substring_ARR); for (;j<=l;j+=2) substring_ARR[j]+=i;                               #-- update the cut position of the fields, after the inserted star field
                        }
                     else { j=star_i*2-1; delete substring_ARR[j]; delete substring_ARR[j+1]; }                      #-- field length ==0 -> delete reserved places
                     }
                  #-- write fields -- star_found is used to save the cut position
                  i=1; star_found=0; for (j in substring_ARR) { if (star_found==0) star_found=j; else { $i=substr(RT, substring_ARR[star_found], substring_ARR[j]); star_found=0; i++ }}
                  NF=i-1; break;
                  
               case "FPAT": patsplit(RT, fields); for (i in fields) $i=fields[i]; NF=length(fields); break;
               }
            }
         $0=RT; RT=""; return 1;
         }
      else return 0;                  #-- record is last one and record length was smaller than width, $0 contains the record, RT=""
      }
   else return -1;
   }
   
BEGIN {
FIELDWIDTHS="15 10 4";
load_fixedWidth_record(29, 1);
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i;
} ' <<< "4harddisk-------412999238---13cdrom-------------488388---22floppy-----------4994942---31mouse-----------20303202---4"
```

Comment: what exactly are you asking about? it looks (to me) like a request for a code review but we're given no info on the overall design of your process nor are we given any info on the actual data (sample input, source of data, expected output); I've only read through the 'question' twice but all I have are a lot of questions ... why are you using RS/RT to parse data? why are you using a mix of FS, FIXEDWIDTH and FPAT to further parse the data? what is the purpose of the *`two way pipe`* and the need to *`send data back`*?

Comment: what do you mean by 'stream'? is the input coming from a process that periodically spits out incomplete sets of data (hence the `RS=.{width}`)? is this supposed to be some sort of general-purpose data parsing function that you're calling from a host of different processes and hence the dynamic processing based on FS, FIXEDWIDTH, FPAT?

Comment: I'd recommend starting over from scratch with a new question; provide info on the source (stream?) of input data, sample input data, how the data is to be processed, and the expected output; if you really do have multi-formatted data (ie, the requirement for FS, FIXEDWIDTH and FPAT) then I'd probably start with one type of format, get a working solution, then try to modify said solution to work with the other two formats; once all 3 formats are addressed then look at if/how to merge into a single set of code

Comment: @markp-fuso i have a binary file, awk <file, starting reading the signature, and then the header with 256 bytes segments, 8 byte tag, 4 byte type, ......, 4byte CRC.. Generally i want to read out a fixed width record of 256 byte characters, and then use awk FIXEDWIDTHS field splitting, using $1...$n, how can this be done?  When I use RS=".{256}", i load 256 byte characters into RT, but than i have no field splitting from awk, how can i use awks field splitting?????? can this be done, has this to be coded manually?

Comment: @markp-fuso sorry i use awk -b <file

Comment: @markp-fuso changed the question to very simple....

Comment: @Schmaehgrunza: What have your tried?  I think the main problem is with the RS, not with the FIELDWIDTHS (I am talking about gawk, not awk)

Comment: @Luuk i cleared my tries, because markp-fuso told me no one is understanding my question - now you want my tries lol. what i tried is, to set REGEXP to RS=".{29}"; so i can read the record into RT, but than $0 is empty, but how can i then use awks field splitting(FIXEDWIDTHS), that was my first question including my tries.

Comment: "Can it be done with using field splitting (FIELDWIDTHS) of awk?"  the code you tried is currently missing, now the question is pretty vague, and does not show effort (so I can/will not upvoted it....)

Comment: @Luuk you need not to upvote this question, points are not important for me, i only want to know, if there is an easy way to tell awk read in a record of 29 chars, and use field splitting of FIXEDWIDTHS, without any long coding. i reinserted my tries.

Comment: the details you've added in comments (eg, reading binary file, header, 256 btye chunks, etc) should be placed in the question, preferably at the top; not everyone will read through the comments trying to piece together the entire picture

Comment: Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

Comment: @marp-fuso i've inserted a very simple text example of data,

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output given the sample input you provided. Also - you seem to have put a lot of information in comments, don't do that, make sure all of the information we need to help you is stated in your question where it can be properly formatted and can't be missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can set `RS="$^"` to indicate the entire file is to be treated as one long record.

One idea using a `while` loop and 3x `substr()` calls to strip off chunks:

```
awk -b '                                             # read characters as bytes (per comment from OP)
BEGIN { RS = "^$" }
      { while (length($0)>1) {                       # keep splitting input line until it is empty
              f1   = substr($0,1 ,15)
              f2   = substr($0,16,10)
              f3   = substr($0,26, 4)

              print "############"
              print "f1:",f1
              print "f2:",f2
              print "f3:",f3

              $0 = substr($0,30)                     # strip off first 29 chars
        }
      }
' raw.dat
```

Another `while` loop but this one uses `match()` to replace the 3x `substr()` calls:

```
awk -b '
BEGIN { RS = "^$" }
      { while (match($0,/(.{15})(.{10})(.{4})/,arr)) {

              print "############"
              print "f1:",arr[1]
              print "f2:",arr[2]
              print "f3:",arr[3]

              $0 = substr($0,RLENGTH+1)              # strip off first 29 chars
        }
      }
' raw.dat
```

Another `while` loop and a `FIELDWIDTHS` with a wildcard for the 4th field:

```
awk -b '
BEGIN { RS = "^$"
        FIELDWIDTHS = "15 10 4 *"                    # "*" allows us to define 4th field as "rest of record"
      }
      { while (length($3)==4) {

              print "############"
              print "f1:",$1
              print "f2:",$2
              print "f3:",$3

              $0 = $4                                # redefine $0 as $4 (rest of record) and force a reparse based on FIELDWIDTHS
        }
      }
' raw.dat
```

**NOTE:** see [Capturing Optional Trailing Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Allowing-trailing-data) for the use of `*` in `FIELDWIDTHS`

All of these generate:

```
############
f1: 4harddisk------
f2: -412999238
f3: ---1
############
f1: 3cdrom---------
f2: ----488388
f3: ---2
############
f1: 2floppy--------
f2: ---4994942
f3: ---3
############
f1: 1mouse---------
f2: --20303202
f3: ---4
```

OP will probably want to add some extra code (after the `while` loop) to handle anything at the end of the record that is less than 29 bytes in length.

---

If OP has a need to implement different `FIELDWIDTHS` settings as procoessing progresses, this can be done by simply defining a new `FIELDWIDTHS` and then forcing the current line of data to be reparsed (eg, `$0=$0`).

Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77816562) where 3x different `FIELDWIDTHS` settings are stored in an array; as the data is processed a new `FIELDWIDTHS` is defined based on the 1st two characters in the record.

Comment: Cool you got the solution for my problem!!!!, i didnt know that, everytime i set a new value to $0, awk splits it in fields again according to PROCINFO["FS"] .... thats the solution, thx!!!!!! i only need to set $0 to force it to field splitting.  In your examples you read the complete file, that means i have to read the complete binary to only examine the header. but i can do the following. FIELDSWIDTH="15 10 4"; RS=".{29}"; getline; $0=RT;  -> field splitting happens, thx man

Comment: @Schmaehgrunza if you don't need to process the entire file then you can issue an `exit` once you've obtained the needed data, ie, `FIXEDWIDTHS="..."; $0=...; {process data}; exit`; upon hitting `exit` the `awk` script will ... exit; if the script needs to process multiple files you can use `nextfile` to jump ahead to the next input file

Comment: But if i use RS="^$", doesnt that mean i load the complete binary file into memory? - because $0 got the length, and all the binary characters. On the other side I tried it with a VOB file of 780 MB, it took awk 1.4 seconds  on my computer to load it, but i never will get in contact with such big sizes. i think i can use also RS="^$" without loosing to much speed.

Comment: yeah, you're right, I misread your comment (thought you were talking about having to parse/process the entire file); personally, I'd probably use `head` to pull the first XXX bytes (eg, `awk '....' < <(head -c XXX raw.dat)`)

Answer (score 2):

I try to answer: "how can you read out this data with awk"

Reading this using awk is failing on my side too, because of the definition of records (from the man page):

> Records
> Normally,  records  are  separated by newline characters.  You can control how records are separated by assigning values to
> the built-in variable RS.  If RS is any single character, that character separates records.  Otherwise, RS is a regular ex‐
> pression.   Text  in  the input that matches this regular expression separates the record.  However, in compatibility mode,
> only the first character of its string value is used for separating records.  If RS is set to the null string, then records
> are  separated  by empty lines.  When RS is set to the null string, the newline character always acts as a field separator,
> in addition to whatever value FS may have.

To solve this you might try splitting the long text into records first:

```
sed -e 's/\(.\{29\}\)/\1\n/g' input
```

output:

```
4harddisk-------412999238---1
3cdrom-------------488388---2
2floppy-----------4994942---3
1mouse-----------20303202---4
```

Then you can use gawk, using [FIELDWIDTHS](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html#:%7E:text=non%2DEnglish%20locales.-,FIELDWIDTHS,-A%20whitespace%2Dseparated), or whatever you think works...

Comment: i upvoted this, its a possibility for text, but not for binary, in markp-fuso answer, i see, you only have to set a new value to $0, and awk splits in fields again. every time you set $0, awk splits. I didnt know this! thats the solution

Answer (score 1):

In markp-fuso's answer, I've seen, that simply setting a value to $0, forces awk to split in fields again according to PROCINFO["FS"].

Every set of $0 -> awk split in fields. I didnt know this!!!
So i can simply do this, without reading the whole file at once

```
awk '   
BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS="15 10 4"; RS=".{29}" }
{
if (length(RT)>0) $0=RT;  #-- $0=RT -> setting $0 -> awk splits in field according fieldswidth
if (length($0)>1) printf "%s\n", $1 " : " $2 " : " $3;  #-- get rid off here strings 0A
}' <<< "4harddisk-------412999238---13cdrom-------------488388---22floppy-----------4994942---31mouse-----------20303202---4"
```

thx, to all!!

Answer (score 1):

`mmap` based solution in TXR Lisp:

The program maps the file as an array of structures (whose type is named `rec`), then iterates over them to print the structures in their Lisp syntax:

```
$ txr mmap.tl
#S(rec name "4harddisk------" id "-412999238" code "---1")
#S(rec name "3cdrom---------" id "----488388" code "---2")
#S(rec name "2floppy--------" id "---4994942" code "---3")
#S(rec name "1mouse---------" id "--20303202" code "---4")
```

code:

```
(typedef rec (struct rec
               (name (array 15 char))
               (id (array 10 char))
               (code (array 4 char))))

(defun round-up-to (pow2 value)
  (logand (+ value pow2 -1)
          (lognot (pred pow2))))

(let* ((f (open-file "data"))
       (s (stat f))
       (n (trunc s.size (sizeof rec)))
       (ap (mmap (ffi rec)
                 (round-up-to page-size s.size)
                 prot-read map-shared f)))
  (each ((i 0..n))
    (prinl [ap i])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do, using GNU awk for multi-char `RS` and `RT`:

```
$ awk -v RS='.{29}' -F'-+' '{$0=RT; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' file
4harddisk
412999238
1
3cdrom
488388
2
2floppy
4994942
3
1mouse
20303202
4
```

or maybe this, using GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, `RT`, `FIELDWIDTHS`, and `gensub()`?

```
$ awk -v RS='.{29}' -v FIELDWIDTHS='15 10 4' '{$0=RT; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print gensub(/-+/,"","g",$i)}' file
4harddisk
412999238
1
3cdrom
488388
2
2floppy
4994942
3
1mouse
20303202
4
```

Comment: Yes, the second method, thx